# SQL Join and Distinct and Max Problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB with two type of reports being added weekly but on different dates: ActiveSystems, LicenseReports. Both have a report date, both have a corresponding serial number.

I need an sql query that provides all the latest ActiveSystems and the first matching row in the LicenseReport table from the latest date as well. Here's a bit of an example:

```
ActiveSystem
ReportDate    SerialNo
9/03/18       111111
9/03/18       112211
9/03/18       114411
9/10/18       111111
9/10/18       112211
9/10/18       113311


LicenseReports
ReportDate    Serial_Number
9/7/18        111111
9/7/18        111111
9/7/18        112211
9/7/18        112211
```

I need every item from the latest date in the ActiveSystem list, but only the first matching serial number in the LicenseReport table, which may or may not exist.

So far I have something like this

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports]  AS ASR 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LicenseReports] AS LCR ON ASR.SerialNo = LCR.Serial_Number
Where ASR.ReportDate >= (SELECT MAX(ReportDate) From [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports]) AND 
LCR.ReportDate >= (SELECT MAX(ReportDate) From [dbo].[LicenseReports])
```

But this doesn't return all the records from the First table and contains duplicates for all matching records in the second table. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

My expected output is:

```
ActiveSystem                     LicenseReport
ReportDate    SerialNo  ect      ReportDate     Serial_Number
9/10/18       111111    ...      9/7/18         111111
9/10/18       112211    ...      9/7/18         112211
9/10/18       113311    ...      null           null
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? Your query has many logical issues going on. If you are trying to get the most recent for each serialNo this is not the way to do that. What do you expect as output from your sample data?

Comment: Edit the question add your expected result based on sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` and order by row_number for the ReportDate of the LicenseReports?

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ASR.*, LCR.*
FROM [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports] AS ASR
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LicenseReports] AS LCR
  ON ASR.SerialNo = LCR.Serial_Number
WHERE ASR.ReportDate = (SELECT MAX(ReportDate) FROM [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports])
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ASR.Serial_Number ORDER BY LCR.ReportDate DESC);
```

Comment: This seems to accomplish the task. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3434042 Thanks.  Btw, it uses `=` in the WHERE because it's already comparing to a MAX of the same table, so `>=` wouldn't find any higher date than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY  instead of left join.
Please Check following Query For More Details.

```
SELECT ASR.* , D.Serial_Number as LicenseReportsDate
FROM [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports]  AS ASR 
OUTER APPLY
(
    select TOP 1 Serial_Number from [dbo].[LicenseReports] AS LCR
    where LCR ON ASR.SerialNo = LCR.Serial_Number
    ORder by LCR.ReportDate DESC 
) as  D
```

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me this is hat you need:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT AS.*, LR.ReportDate LicenseReportDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AS.SerialNo ORDER BY LR.ReportDate DESC) N
  FROM ActiveSystemReports AS
  LEFT JOIN LicenseReports LR ON AS.SerialNo=LR.Serial_Number
) T WHERE N=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports]  AS ASR 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(LCR.ReportDate), SerialNo
    FROM [dbo].[LicenseReports]
    GROUP BY SerialNo) AS LCR ON ASR.SerialNo = LCR.Serial_Number
```

Gets the ASR records and the *first* (by date) LCR record for the same serial. Which may not really be what you want as the question's unclear...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT ASR.*, LCR.* 
FROM [dbo].[ActiveSystemReports] AS ASR OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) LCR.*
       FROM [dbo].[LicenseReports] AS LCR
       WHERE LCR.Serial_Number = ASR.SerialNo 
       ORDER BY LCR.ReportDate DESC 
     ) LCR;
```